# Are there any PaxTest for OpenBSD?

Tags: security, freebsd, openbsd, bsd

Pax:

> PaX is a process memory protection patch

For FreeBSD, there exists a testsuite called [PaxTest](https://github.com/opntr/paxtest-freebsd), is there a PaxTest available for OpenBSD?

Comment: I think that this test suite could be user with OpenBSD. There is a OpenBSD makefile on it: https://github.com/opntr/paxtest-freebsd/blob/master/Makefile.OpenBSD - Have you tried to donwnload and compile it?

Comment: please post it as answer!

Comment: Posted as an answer. I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this test suite could be used on OpenBSD.

There is an OpenBSD makefile distributed with it:
github.com/opntr/paxtest-freebsd/blob/master/Makefile.OpenBSD

Comment: additional info in http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/139238/why-does-paxtest-show-openbsd-as-vulnerable